# How to "reset" master to follow HEAD again after `git symbolic-ref`

Tags: git

At some point in the past, I've set `master` to follow my other branch, like this:

```
git symbolic-ref refs/heads/master refs/heads/my-other-branch
```

I want to go back to the state where master just tracks HEAD as usual. Can I just paste the most recent SHA1 into `.git/refs/heads/master`?

Comment: It's worth noting that `master` *doesn't* normally track `HEAD`; normally it's a branch-head containing a raw SHA-1.  It's pretty normal for things to be the other way around though, with `HEAD` an indirect ref pointing to `refs/heads/master`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, but the "officially correct" way is to use `git update-ref` with `--no-deref` to rewrite `refs/heads/master` without following the symbolic indirection that's currently in `refs/heads/master`.

In other words, if `$sha1` is the correct SHA-1, both:

```
echo $sha1 > .git/refs/heads/master
```

and:

```
git update-ref --no-deref refs/heads/master $sha1
```

should work, but the latter is the "right" method, which should continue to work even if git evolves in the future such that the `echo` stops working.  You can add a `-m <reason>` to the latter to add the `<reason>` string to the reflog as well (the direct `echo` method does not update the reflog, while `update-ref` does).